# A question of the proof of Th 8.1.4 in Real Analysis and Probability by Ash

Tags: real-analysis, probability, proof-explanation

In Real Analysis and Probability, Th 8.1.3 used a proposition that

> Let $g$ be a continous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, with compact support, that is for some $T>0$, $g=0$ off $[-T,T]$. since $g(-T)=g(T)=0$,$g$ may be transferred to the unit circle in other words, $g(x)=h(exp\frac{i\pi x}{T}), -T<x<T$, for some continous $h$ from $E=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\lvert z\rvert =1\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$

And I don't understand how this works ? How to consitruct a $h$ like this？

Comment: Can you see how a function $f:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$ can be thought of as a function on the circle? You can assign $\theta \mapsto f(\theta)$. This is just the same thing, but where the interval is not necessarily $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: I think I get it, Thank you son much